# Drunk Silverlight - solid background colors for a button background shows it with gradient effect

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

VS2012 >> New Silverlight project >>

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <Button Background="Red" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

- The silverlight button default template has change somehow.. how i reset and restore to default?
- WPF buttons background works fine
- only buttons issue , for now other controls doesn't have this problem

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like @Alex says, the gradient is a result of the Template used by the Button.  No matter what color you set the background to, it's going to show the gradient.

One way to change this is by modifying the template as @Alex suggested.

Another way is to set the Content of the Button to a Grid, and then set the Grid to whatever solid color you want.

```
<Button Height="100" Click="OnClick" Width="100">
            <Button.Content>
                <Grid Height="100" Width="100" IsHitTestVisible="False" Background="Blue"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
```

Comment: You are all trying to workaround the problem , somehow the default template for silverlight button has changed ,  this is something that happened few days ago, How I reset , undo this change template , I tried use the default button template from Alex link , same result

Comment: The only way to change the template is by setting it in a style.  So unless there is a Style="{StaticResource x:Key=MyStyle}" then it is using the default style.

Comment: The other possibility is that you had a "default" style in a resource file that was getting used automatically.  Then if that style was given a Key, then it is no longer the default, and it would not be used.

Comment: Oh THANK YOU! I knew I could remove the "haze" effect by modifying the template, but it seemed so complicated for something so simple. You're idea worked BRILLIANTLY!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on the template of the button. I'm guessing the default template has some layers on top that simulate translucent shading or something like that. Replace the control template with a simpler one and it should work. You can find the default templates on MSDN, you can just modify the button one instead of starting from scratch: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069(v=vs.95).aspx

Specifically I'm guessing this part is the gradient:

```
<Border x:Name="Background" CornerRadius="3" Background="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  Margin="1">
        <Border Opacity="0"  x:Name="BackgroundAnimation" Background="#FF448DCA" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
     </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a workaround , I wanna silverlight default button to behave&look like silverlight default button, + I tried this default button style.. same result

Comment: I meant use this style but remove the rectangle with the gradient. The default silverlight button does have a highlight on it, so that's what you're getting I suppose.

Comment: lets ask this , how I reset / restore silverlight templates to default ?

Comment: If you're not changing them you already have the defaults. If you're changing them then don't change them... I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.